# Laravel: error prompts when attempting multi-page form creation

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

I tried to do a multipage form using laravel livewire following this tutorial https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-multi-step-form-example-tutorialexample.html
However, this error keeps appearing at here

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the prducts.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();

        return view('products.index',compact('products'));
    }
```

which appears change @return type to \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View

What could possibly be the problem, Is it the tutorial being outdated or there is other stuff needed to be tweak?

Comment: make sure your products folder and inside index.blade.php file and check again. and also make sure your product modal like this: use App\Models\Product;

Comment: you can find out same project here : https://github.com/Delowar-Hossen/laravel-multi-step-form please download and create database from env file and check.